# How can we tell file descriptrs for controlling terminal from for noncontrolling terminal?

Tags: c, linux, terminal

If a process has opened  more than one terminals, how can we know which file descriptors are for the controlling terminals of the process' session, and which are for noncontrolling terminals?

Originated from https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/446207/for-a-process-what-are-the-differences-between-a-controlling-terminal-and-non-c

Comment: Show the code creating terminals and having the file descriptors you are talking about, and then we can tell whether or not there is a difference between them.

Comment: What makes you think any of them are controlling terminals?  If the process is started with a controlling terminal, probability is very high that the related fds are 0, 1, and 2.  Descriptors that you create are up to your process to keep track of.

Comment: @WilliamPursell I was wondering if any existing fd is for controlling terminal if any, and how to tell them apart from those for noncontrolling terminal.

Comment: [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html) says _3.115 **Controlling Terminal**
A terminal that is associated with a session. Each session may have at most one controlling terminal associated with it, and a controlling terminal is associated with exactly one session. Certain input sequences from the controlling terminal cause signals to be sent to all processes in the foreground process group associated with the controlling terminal._ A process can only be associated with a single session, so a process can only have, at most, one controlling terminal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A process does not necessarily have *any* fds open on its controlling tty.  However, if a process has a controlling terminal, it can open `/dev/tty` to get an fd for it.  (If it doesn't have a controlling tty, opening `/dev/tty` will fail with, um, ENXIO, apparently, this isn't documented anywhere I can find, and honestly I would have expected ENODEV or ENOTTY instead, but it's consistent across Linux and NetBSD so it's probably an official spec *somewhere*.)

Learning whether an fd is open on the calling process's controlling tty is more difficult than it might seem.  The obvious thing to do is, first, verify that it's open on *some* tty with `isatty`, and then call `tcgetpgrp` on it.  `tcgetpgrp` is documented to fail if its fd argument does not refer to the calling process's controlling tty.  Unfortunately, Linux at least also allows one to call `tcgetpgrp` on the outside of a pseudoterminal (this is what you get when you open `/dev/ptmx`), and I'm not having any luck finding a good way to distinguish an actual tty from the outside of a pseudoterminal; `isatty` will be true for both, most of the other terminal-related operations can be applied to both, and so on.  You might have to resort to `fstat` and decoding `st_rdev`.  Blech.

Comment: ENXIO is [documented](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html) as *"The named file is a character special or block special file, and the device associated with this special file does not exist."* so it does make sense.. kinda.

Comment: Thanks. " I'm not having any luck finding a good way to distinguish an actual tty from the outside of a pseudoterminal". Do you mean the master, slave or both sides of a pseudoterminal, by "the outside of a pseudoterminal"?

Comment: I mean what people other than me call the master.  I avoid using "master" and "slave" as computer jargon, for philosophical reasons; in this case I also think "outside" and "inside" are conceptually clearer.

Comment: Thanks. I was wondering what kind of processes satisfy that "if a process has a controlling terminal, it can open /dev/tty to get an fd for it"? The following kinds of processes don't seem so: "processes that the session leader forked before attaching to a controlling tty ...are not entirely part of the session, in the same way that processes that have detached from the controlling tty are not entirely part of the session... can't open /dev/tty,"

Comment: @Tim I don't know how to answer that any clearer than I already have. A process can open /dev/tty if and only if it has a controlling terminal.  There are many situations where a process might not have a controlling terminal.

Comment: Sorry I was not clear. If a process "doesn't have a controlling tty, opening /dev/tty will fail". So opening /dev/tty isn't a way to obtain a controlling terminal. How does the first process which has a controlling terminal obtain it?

Comment: @Tim Be a session leader without a controlling tty, then open some concrete terminal device without using the `O_NOCTTY` flag.  Does APUE really not explain this process?  You might find it edifying to read through the code of `mingetty`.

Comment: Thanks. If a process "doesn't have a controlling tty, opening /dev/tty will fail" (in your reply), how does "a session leader without a contorlling tty" " open some concrete terminal device" (in your comment)? Or is the latter is an exception to the former?

Comment: Concrete terminal devices are all the *other* character special files in /dev whose names begin with "tty" but then have something else tacked on, e.g. /dev/tty0, /dev/ttyS0, /dev/ttyUSBblah.  Also the inner-side pseudoterminal devices, /dev/pts/0 and so on.

Comment: I see. Thank you!